# How often has an unseeded woman player gotten to/won the Finals in a Grand Slam tournament?

Tags: tennis

If unseeded Shuai Peng manages to beat Caroline Wozniacki in the semi-finals of the U.S. Open (unlikely in my opinion), she will face either Serena Williams or Ekaterina Makarova in the finals. And if Peng wins the final, she will be an unseeded woman Grand Slam winner.

How often has that happened in the past? And to whom?

Comment: The list of GS finals at Wikipedia contains also seedings of the finalists: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Open_Era_Grand_Slam_men's_singles_finals The seedings are not shown in analogous list of women's finalists: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Open_Era_Grand_Slam_women's_singles_finals

Comment: From TennisForum: [Most surprising runs by unseeded players at Grand Slams?](http://www.tennisforum.com/showthread.php?t=372281) and [Best Unseeded Players at the Grand Slams since 1989](http://www.tennisforum.com/showthread.php?t=368148). From MensTennisForums: [Greatest Unseeded/WC/Q run at a Grand Slam?](http://www.menstennisforums.com/showthread.php?t=152131)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Open_Era_Grand_Slam_men's_singles_finals) has a list of the men's singles Grand Slam finals in the Open Era, and it shows the player seedings.  There have been 30 unseeded men's Grand Slam finalists since 1968.  Eight of those players won the final.  There has never been a men's Grand Slam final in the Open Era in which both players were unseeded.

The Tennis Channel has [an article](http://www.tennischannel.com/news/NewsDetails.aspx?newsid=6590) that lists the unseeded women's Grand Slam finalists of the Open Era up to January 2010.  There were 11 unseeded women's Grand Slam finalists between 1968 and the 2010 Australian Open, and 3 of them won the final.